# How do I create an oblong torus with a constant thickness?

Tags: modeling

I've tried making a torus and stretching it and making an oval curve and beveling a circle on it, but with both methods the torus ends up getting thicker on the sides that are stretched out. Is there any way to keep the minor radius constant along the whole shape?

Comment: Create a mesh circle. Tab to edit mode and stretch along one axis. Tab back to object mode. Convert to curve `Alt` `C` > `C`. Bevel it. Convert back to mesh `Alt` `C` > `M`. Neither Bezier nor Nurbs curves can exactly represent elliptical shapes, not even circles. They approximate circles fairly well, but with ellipses, their shortcomings in this department become painfully apparent.

Comment: @SixthOfFour you should write that as an answer (preferably with screenshots).

Comment: @AWildRolandiXor The reason I wrote it as a comment, is that I'm not at my blending computer, thus I can't make any screenshots. I'll post an answer though, and add screenshots later.

Comment: Yeah, in cases where your comment is an answer it's best to add the answer (unless you think the question might be off topic, but you can provide a solution in a comment while flagging/voting to close). You can always edit answers later to provide improvements, etc.

Answer (score 9):

If you stretch a torus, both the major and the minor radii will be stretched, so the effect you see is perfectly normal. There may be some way to remedy that, but I haven't found it. I have come up with some workarounds though.

---

## Method 1

Add a mesh circle.
<kbd>Tab</kbd> into Edit mode<sup>1</sup>.
Scale it along one axis, <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>.
<kbd>Tab</kbd> back to Object mode.
Convert the circle, which should now be an ellipse, to a curve <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > <kbd>C</kbd>.
Put a bevel on it. If you want a circular tube, you needn't use a bevel object. Just set the bevel depth and resolution to whatever rocks your boat and set Fill to Full.
When you're happy with it, convert it back to a mesh <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > <kbd>M</kbd>.
Unfortunately I haven't been able to find out how to include the menus when I take screenshots, so this doesn't show the conversion between mesh and curve and back.
[image]

The reason I don't use a curve directly, is that neither Bezier nor Nurbs curves represent elliptical object very well. They approximate circles acceptably, but with ellipses they fail miserably unless you give them a ridiculous amount of vertices.

---

## Method 2

If you have the Extra Objects addon installed and activated, you can use XYZ Math surface to create a torus object of practically any shape.

To enable this addon, go to User Preferences <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> > Add-ons > Add Mesh > Add Mesh: Extra Objects.
[image]

Add > Mesh > Math Function > XYZ Math Surface

For an elliptical torus with a major axis of 3, a minor axis of 1 and a circular tube with a radius of 0.25

X equation:
(3+.25*cos(u))*cos(v)

Y equation:
(1+.25*cos(u))*sin(v)

Z equation:
.25*sin(u)

U min and V min: 0
U max and V max: 2*pi
U wrap, V wrap and Close V enabled.

[image]

The normals will be pointing inwards, so you'll need to flip them. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into Edit mode and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate them to point outwards.
[image]

---

## Method 3

Here's a third method that I discovered today, when reading [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26407/skin-modifier-giving-wierd-geometry). It uses the Skin modifier, which is something I've never used before. This seems to be the simplest method, and very straightforward, and that's the reason I'm making this late addition.

Add a mesh circle.
<kbd>Tab</kbd> into Edit mode<sup>1</sup>.
Scale it along one axis, <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>.
<kbd>Tab</kbd> back to Object mode.
[image]

Add a Skin modifier.
[image]

Add a Subdivision Surface modifier. As pointed out by PGmath in a comment to this answer, the Catmull-Clark algorithm doesn't produce a perfect circle, and depending on your need for accuracy in the shape of the skin, you may want to consider using one of the first two methods instead.
[image]

The radius of the skin can be scaled. Make sure the Skin modifier is still in the modifier stack, i.e. do **not** apply it.
<kbd>Tab</kbd> into Edit mode.
Make sure everything is selected (<kbd>A</kbd> once or twice).
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and then drag the mouse or use the arrow keys on your keyboard until you're happy with the thickness. <kbd>Enter</kbd> or left mouse button to confirm.
[image]

---

<sup>1</sup>Scaling in Edit mode is essentially the same as scaling in Object mode and then applying the scale.

Comment: BTW, you can use alt+shift+S (I think that's the right combo, if not somebody can correct me) to change the skin radius.  And also, *technically* Catmul-Clark subdivision doesn't converge to a circle (off the top of my head I think it converges to a cubic polynomial), so the cross section won't be a perfect circle.

Comment: @PGmath I know it doesn't make a perfect circle, and the first two methods are more accurate. I still think this third method is very usable though, and the cross section is closer to a circle than a Bézier or Nurbs  scaled on one axis would be to an ellipse.

Comment: @PGmath I just consulted the Blender Wiki on the [Skin modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Skin_Modifier), and the radius can be adjusted with Ctrl+A in Edit mode. I'm a little busy right now, but I'll update my answer when I have a chance. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Methods 1 and 3 in the other answer are definitely good, and worthy of an upvote. However, method 2 leaves a little to be desired. The standard equations for a circular torus won't yield an elliptic torus with constant thickness. It will be more visible the more eccentric the ellipse gets.

[image]

I'm working on my first ever Blender add-on, which (if all goes well) will add tori of different configurations. Currently I have the elliptic torus in working order, and I'm happy to share it, if anyone would be interested. It's available from my GitHub repo [Tori](https://github.com/DuaneDibbley/Tori). Just click **Clone or download** and save it to your harddrive.

To install it, open up Blender, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> to open up *User Preferences*.
Click Add-ons, then *Install Add-on from File* and select the file you downloaded (Tori-master.zip).

[image]

You should now see the following.

[image]

Click the chek box next to *Add Mesh: Tori*, and the add-on should be working. If you want to make it survive restarts, also click the *Save User Settings* button.

There should now be an *Elliptic Torus* entry on the *Add -> Mesh* menu.

[image]

The options are as follows

*Major Semi-Radius* is half the size of the major axis of the ellipse.
*Minor Semi-Radius* is half the size of the major axis of the ellipse.
*Tube Radius* is the radius of the cross-section.
*Ellipse Segments* is the number of segements into which the ellipse is divided.
*Tube Segments* is the number of segements into which the cross-section is divided.

---

As this add-on stands right now, it's not that useful, as this can be easily achieved by other means. However, I do have some plans for tori with configurations that none of the available torus add-ons handle, and this is just the initial setup and part of my learning process. Specifically I'm aiming to get an elliptic torus with constant thickness but parallel cross-sections working.